# Exact sequences of the cohomology induced by fiber bundle

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

I'm reading section 2.1 of Lawson's book, Spin Geometry. The book states the following fact. Let $X$ be a manifold and $E$ a vector bundle over it. Equip $E$ with a Riemannian structure. Let $P_O$ be the bundle of orthonormal frames in $E$ which is a principal $O_n$ bundle. The fibration $O_n \rightarrow P_O(E) \rightarrow X$  gives an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow H^{0}(X;\mathbb{Z}_2)  \rightarrow H^{0}(P_O(E);\mathbb{Z}_2) \rightarrow H^{0}(O_n;\mathbb{Z}_2) \rightarrow H^{1}(X;\mathbb{Z}_2) $ and the fibration $SO_n \rightarrow P_{SO}(E) \rightarrow X$ gives another exact sequence $0 \rightarrow H^{1}(X;\mathbb{Z}_2)  \rightarrow H^{1}(P_{SO}(E);\mathbb{Z}_2) \rightarrow H^{1}(SO_n;\mathbb{Z}_2) \rightarrow H^{2}(X;\mathbb{Z}_2)  $. Lawson only says that we can deduce them from Serre spectral sequence but I don't know how. Could someone give an explicit recipe? (By the way, we are around page 79 to page 81.)

Thank you.

Comment: The space $P_{SO}(E)$ in the second statement becomes defined only when when the vector is oriented, so the second statement makes sense only in that case. It is true if in addition $X$ is connected (which I imagine is being assumed).

Comment: The first statement is false when $X$ is a point.

Comment: ("when the vector bundle is oriented", I meant in my first comment)

Comment: The second exact sequence is (part of) what's sometimes called the *Serre spectral sequence*. It's deduced from the Serre spectral sequence as in Example 1.A of McCleary's "User's guide to spectral sequences".

Comment: Can you elaborate how this is related to example 1.A?

Comment: @Kofi: Yes, just apply the result of Example 1.A to the cohomology Serre spectral sequence of the fibration $SO_n\to P_{SO}(E)\to X$. See also Example 5.D in the same book.

Comment: @MarkGrant Naively applying 5.D does not seem to work because $p+q-1=1$ in this case. Does one have to do something special with 1.A, perhaps related to the mod 2 coefficients?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are asking about is a consequence of a more general statement about fibrations. Let $p: E \to B$ be a fibration with $B$ path connected and based. Set $F = p^{-1}(*)$. 
Assume $B$ is $r$-connected and $p$ is $s$-connected. Then there's a exact sequence
$$
0 \to H^0(B) \to H^0(E) \to H^0(F) \to H^1(B) \to \cdots \to H^{r+s}(F) \to H^{r+s+1}(B) 
$$
One way to prove this is to show that the evident map  $E \cup CF \to B$, whose domain is the mapping cone of $F\to E$, is $(r+s+2)$-connected. There are a variety of ways to show this, one of which is called the "dual Blakers-Massey Theorem."  Then the long exact cohomology sequence of the cofiber sequence $F \to E \to E\cup CF$ combined with the connectivity statement gives what you want.

Comment: In the case in the OP, neither $F$ nor $B$ are 1-connected, so how does one get to $H^2(B)$?

Comment: If $F,B$ are $0$-connected, then the map $H^2(B) \to H^2(E\cup CF)$ is injective. The exactness on the right is $\cdots \to H^1(F) \to H^2(E\cup CF)$. There is no a priori reason in general for the image of this last map to factor through $H^2(B)$. It does factor through $H^1(\Omega B)$. So there is a question about a transgression in this case.

Comment: Alternatively, there is a map $H^1(F) \to H^2(\tilde B)$ which fits the exact sequence above, where $\tilde B$ is the universal cover of $B$. All this makes me slightly skeptical that Lawson's second sequence is correct. But he's working mod 2. Maybe that makes all the difference.

Comment: It's unclear to me what are the maps. In particular, I have a problem with the $0$-th dimension situation. Suppose $r,s\geq 0$, then $F,E,B$ are all connected and thus $H^0$ is free of rank 1, and the beginning of this sequence can't happen with the obvious maps. In n-lab the homological sequence stops in degree 1, is this also the case here?

Comment: @NoamZimhoni In the sequence I exhibited $H^\ast(-)$ means reduced cohomology. In particular,  $H^0(X)$ is trivial if $X$ is connected.